# Buffer N values per second RxJava, Project Reactor

Tags: rxjs, rx-java2, project-reactor

I have a stream with some values:

`Flux<Integer> stream = getStream();`

And I was trying to implement N items per second functionality

```
stream.bufferTimeout(MAX_SIZE_TWO, _1_SECOND).subscribe(val => {
  System.out.println(val);
});
```

I am trying to find operator that close to my expected result.

Expected result:

```
time: 15:00:00, stream_next_value: 1, output: {1}
time: 15:00:00, stream_next_value: 2, output: {2}
time: 15:00:00, stream_next_value: 3, no output => buffer
time: 15:00:00, stream_next_value: 4, no output => buffer
time: 15:00:00, stream_next_value: 5, no output => buffer
time: 15:00:01, stream_no_next_value, output: {3,4}
time: 15:00:01, stream_next_value: 6, no output => buffer
time: 15:00:02, stream_no_next_value, output: {5,6}
```

But looks like overloaded versions of buffer operator does not support this behavior.

How to achieve expected behavior using buffer operator ?

Comment: Trying to help here but I miss some information. 
Could you explain what is the nature and the frequency of your stream ? 
Ideally, could you put a minimal, reproductible example  for the input stream (`interval` operator for example) with what result you expect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can do this:

```java
Flowable<Long> stream = Flowable.generate(() -> 0L, (next, emitter) -> {
        emitter.onNext(next);
        return next + 1;
});

// Flowable<Long> stream = Flowable.interval(100, MILLISECONDS);
//                                 .onBackpressureDrop(); // to make it works otherwise get a MissingBackPressureException

stream.buffer(2)
      .zipWith(Flowable.interval(1, SECONDS), (first, second) -> first)
      .flatMap(Flowable::fromIterable)
      .subscribe(s -> LOGGER.info("received: " + s),
                 Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

Beware of `stream` must honor backpressure otherwise you have to add a `onBackpressureXXX()` operator (for instance, that would be the case if stream would be an `interval()` (see commented code)).
You get this kind of output:

```
14:39:59.538 | INFO  | RxComputationThreadPool-1 | received: 0
14:39:59.540 | INFO  | RxComputationThreadPool-1 | received: 1
14:40:00.527 | INFO  | RxComputationThreadPool-1 | received: 2
14:40:00.528 | INFO  | RxComputationThreadPool-1 | received: 3
14:40:01.528 | INFO  | RxComputationThreadPool-1 | received: 4
14:40:01.528 | INFO  | RxComputationThreadPool-1 | received: 5
14:40:02.528 | INFO  | RxComputationThreadPool-1 | received: 6
14:40:02.528 | INFO  | RxComputationThreadPool-1 | received: 7
14:40:03.528 | INFO  | RxComputationThreadPool-1 | received: 8
14:40:03.528 | INFO  | RxComputationThreadPool-1 | received: 9
```